# I cannot access the text of a Web Element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have bunch of `radio buttons`, and would like to get the text from the labels for each of them. This is what I have tried so far:

```
IList<IWebElement> radioButtons = wd.FindElements(By.Name("Components[0].Entity.ComponentSubTypeId"));
foreach (IWebElement i in radioButtons)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i.Text);
}
```

I know that they are getting stored in the `List`, because when I remove the `.Text` from above, a number of `OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement`'s are  written to the Output console, with it matching exactly to the number of `radio buttons` located on the page.

Here is the `HTML` of one of the `radio buttons` on the page:

```
<li class="optionListItem">
   <span class="floatLeftSmallMargin componentTypeOptions">
      <input class="required" id="Components_0__Entity_Entity_ComponentTypeId_PublicationGravure" name="Components[0].Entity.ComponentSubTypeId" type="radio" value="-2147380659" />
   </span>
   <span class="optionListItemText componentTypeOptions">
                        <label for="Components_0__Entity_Entity_ComponentTypeId_PublicationGravure">Publication Gravure</label>
   <span class="helpButton" data-title="Publication Gravure" data-text="A printing method on a substrate that is subsequently formed into books, magazines, catalogues, brochures, directories, newspaper supplements or other types of printed materials.">
   </span>
   </span>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
```

But again, when I append the `.Text` to the index i in the foreach parameter, there is nothing being written to the output console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `IList<IWebElement> radioButtons` does not contain the label.
It only contains the `input` which does not have any text. So when you do `.Text` you will not see any text.

```
IList<IWebElement> labels =  wd.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".optionListItem .optionListItemText label"));
```

Now Iterate on `labels` and call `.Text`, you will see the label names.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it's returning nothing is because the radio buttons indeed don't have text but you selected them, here is a pratical example of how `.Text` works:

```
<li >
    <span id="foo">My text</span>
    <input name="bar" type="radio"/>I'm not part of the radio
</li>
```

Now let's extract the text from above

```
//This will return "My text"
IWebElement spanText= wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#foo")).Text
//This will return empty
IWebElement spanText= wd.FindElement(By.XpathSelector("//input")).Text
```

In your case it should look something like this

```
IList<IWebElement> labels =  wd.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".optionListItem .optionListItemText label"));
foreach (IWebElement i in labels)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i.Text);
}
```

Comment: Also upvoted this answer for the extra info. Thank you Rafael!